# Search for a string in a htm file

Tags: java, android, html

I want to do a school app and therefore I want to do an automatic notification service.
We have for our school something that is called "deputy plan" (Im german.. dont know, if you understand what i mean, but doesnt matter) and it's an online htm file. 
In this file is written which courses are canceled or represented by another teacher.
I want to create a service that recognizes if something that is written in this plan concerns a user of my app.. therefore I want to search for a string in this htm file. Is this possible? 
or do you recommend another method?

Comment: any efforts so far??

Comment: Sry, how do you mean? Are you asking if someone has an idea ? If you mean what i have done so far.. Im so far, that i have the service .. i only have to program what the service should do

Answer (score 3):

Get the page's source

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String row = "";
String text = "";
while ((row = in.readLine()) != null) {
    text += row;
}
in.close();
```

Then find that string in `text`

```
if (text.contains("yourString")) {
    System.out.print("Found!");
}
```

You should try to do your homework yourself by the way